# Debug the method which uses JNDI call in Intellij Idea

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, jndi

In our Java project we have a method which uses `JNDI` to retrieve stub to class `Foo`. After it gets a stub, it calls a method of this method to make some calculations. Here is piece of code to get a feeling of what it looks like:

```
public static String getBar(String id, Map<String, Object> parameters) throws IOException {
    return getFoo().getBar(id, parameters);
}

private static Foo getFoo() throws FooException {
    try {
        InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext
                (FooProperties.getInstance().getProperties());

        return (Foo) PortableRemoteObject.narrow(ctx.lookup(
                "foo-application/" + Foo.JNDI_NAME + "/remote"),
                Foo.class);
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        throw new FooException(FooException.FOO_REMOTE_METHOD_FAILURE, e);
    }
}
```

It gives me unexpected result, so I decided to use debug to understand what's actually going on inside `Foo.getBar()` method. But after I get `Foo` instance, and jvm starts to execute `getBar()` method, I see only calls of inner methods of EJB - `invoke()`, `handleCallLocally()`, `calculateHash()` and stuff like that. But no info about what's going on inside `getBar()`.
So, the question is: how I can take a look at execution of `getBar()` (**if it's possible**).